# JavaScript HTML DOM click() not working on input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to execute a click() on a certain input and the click() method doesn't do anything. Here is my code :

```
document.getElementsByName("op")[1].click()
```

I worked with the chrome console and in a AHK script I have been working with and both don't do anything. I have tried with  : getElementsByName, getElementById, getElementsByClassName... They all don't do anything.

The website is : https://etudier.uqam.ca/cours?sigle=MET5201

**Here are the steps you need to do before clicking the button (input):**

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVQXv.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFy5H.png)

From what I have seen in the HTML code of the page and from some research, I think it does not work because the input is AJAX controlled.

When you click the button, it is supposed to load and tell, for every group, if there is places available.

Comment: Please post all relevant codes and description of your problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click slowly on the button, you'll notice it does not react on `click`, but on `mousedown`. To trigger this event, you can use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Creating_custom_events):

```
// Create a mousedown event and dispatch it
document.getElementsByName("op")[1].dispatchEvent( new Event('mousedown') );
```

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you so much, I'm kind of a noob in javascript and DOM. Your help is really appreciated! Now I just need to convert this code in order to work in a AHK script. I will do some research. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped. I'd never heard of AHK before so I can't be sure, but after quickly looking at [the docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm), it seems you can do it like this: `MouseClick, left, X, Y, 0, D` _(where `X`  & `Y` should be replaced by the button's coordinates, and `D` tells it to only apply a `mousedown`)_

Comment: Yes it is as you say. Here is the code that did the trick : `WB := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")` `MouseDownEvent := WB.document.createEvent("MouseEvent")`
`MouseDownEvent.initMouseEvent("mousedown",true,false, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _)`
`WB.document.getElementsByName("op")[1].dispatchEvent(MouseDownEvent)`